# Hide default column gridview VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a simple question. How can I hide the column below in the red box in windowed application. I am using vb as the programming language

[image]

Comment: That is the row headers, just as they are the column headers across the top. With that in mind, the answer to your question should be obvious from simply reading the documentation for the `DataGridView` class.

Answer (score 1):

There is a property in your `DataGridView` called `RowHeadersVisible` for that purpose.

```
DataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = False
```